# Issue in Webkit browsers with text-shadow in custom fonts

Tags: google-chrome, css

Webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) keep cutting off text-shadow on my custom fonts (from TypeKit). I'm not sure what I can do to fix it. I've been looking around but havent found a similar issue anywhere else.

Screenshot in Google Chrome
[image: Screenshot in Chrome]

Looks fine in Firefox
[image: Screenshot in Firefox (normal)]

Any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Can I see your HTML/CSS code?

Comment: Can't help without css and markup.

Comment: Got it up in a sandbox. [http://sweetlifefestival.islsandbox.com/so/#food](http://sweetlifefestival.islsandbox.com/so/#food)

Comment: Quote @emrah: _"Firefox is not webkit based"_.  What are you talking about?  Nobody said it was.

Comment: @Sparky672 look at the title.

Comment: @emrah, There's nothing in the title about Firefox... again, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem because webkit makes the text node box too small to accomedate the font. Probably due to its cursive style etc.

Add a `&nbsp;` to the end of the text and you will see it works. To offset the extra space that creates you could use a negative right margin. If the only problem is the headers this should work fine...

```
margin-right: -4px;
```

Fiddle arround with the value until you get it right

Comment: btw I like those text-shadow transitions, thats a suprisingly cool effect

Comment: ah, not the most elegant solution but definitely works. I'm surprised no one else has encountered this issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on line 286 of your style.css file change `text-shadow` property's value to `5px 5px 1px #B2CA52`